# Dell Latitude 7490 Linux Installation unsuccessfull on new SSD

Tags: linux, ubuntu, system-installation, nixos, qubes

I’m having problems with my Latitude 7490.
I’ve been using the laptop without issues ever since, mainly using **Qubes, which currently runs without issues.**
Recently, I installed a bigger SSD and wanted to reinstall a fresh OS, this is when the problems started.

Installation of QubesOS 4.1.2:

- In both boot modes (legacy and UEFI), the installer doesn’t start properly or sometimes freezes during installation.

Installation of Kubuntu 22.04 LTS or NixOS 22:

- In both cases the live version running from the USB stick works fine
- Installation finishes without error
- After a reboot from the internal SSD, the display and keyboard input freezes after a few seconds. (Sometimes before logging in and sometimes after)

My hardware is:

- Motherboard:  Dell 0KP0FT
- CPU:      Intel i5-8250U
- Graphics: Intel UHD 620 (Device 5917)

Troubleshooting steps:

- To rule out SSD Problems I cloned the old partition to the new disk using `ddrescue`.
  Result: New SSD with old OS works without any issue.

Please help me where the issue might be.